# How much time it will take to change android app UI text from English to Arabic?

Tags: android, android-layout, localization, arabic, localizable.strings

I am new to android localization process. **How much time it will take for a developer to change an android travel app with almost 70 screens from English to Arabic(Right to Left text direction).** Is it really complicated with Arabic text with right to left combination. **How it will affect my normal static UI and dynamic UI.**

Comment: It depends if this project was made using proper strings extraction and if layouts support RTL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't take too much time if you know how to translate to Arabic. If you created your project using the Android SDK Tools this can easily be done, once again depending if you know your Arabic or you can use google translate. Here's a useful website for more information.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages